# Telerik GridView For WPF Group Aggregate Columns

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik, radgridview

I am trying and failing to show the group totals aligned with column headers. by setting the following properties ShowGroupHeaderColumnAggregates and ShowHeaderAggregates as stated you should be able to here [Telerik Grouping Documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/gridview-grouping-aggregates.html)

[image]

This the XAML I am using - am I doing something wrong or does it just not work? The property setters seem to have no effect.

```
<Window x:Class="GridViewTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:t="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="t:GroupHeaderRow">
        <Setter Property="ShowGroupHeaderColumnAggregates" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="ShowHeaderAggregates" Value="False" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <t:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Records}" SelectionMode="Extended">
        <t:RadGridView.GroupDescriptors>
            <t:GroupDescriptor Member="Column1" SortDirection="Ascending">
                <t:GroupDescriptor.AggregateFunctions>
                    <t:CountFunction Caption="Entries count: " />
                    <t:FirstFunction Caption="First entry: " />
                </t:GroupDescriptor.AggregateFunctions>
            </t:GroupDescriptor>
        </t:RadGridView.GroupDescriptors>
    </t:RadGridView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting RadGridView GroupRenderMode=Flat